# Como poder listar el valor absoluto de su diferencia menores a la cantidad mínima de reposición en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito listar código, nombre, cantidades en stock, cantidad mínima de reposición (reorderLevel) y el valor absoluto de su diferencia, para todos los productos que tengan unidades en stock menores a la cantidad mínima de reposición.

No logro generar el valor absoluto correcto de la columna reorderLevel

Tengo armada la siguiente sintaxis:

```
Select ProductID, 
       ProductName, 
       UnitsInStock, 
       ReorderLevel, 
       abs(ReorderLevel < UnitsInStock)"unidad por debajo del mínimo"
from products;
```

Estoy tranajando en la base de datos Northwind de MySql tabla products

Comment: Con esta consulta ¿qué resultado obtienes y cuál es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: El resultado esperado sería el siguiente:                                                 
ProductID: 3  ProductName: Aniseed Syrup  UnitsInStock: 3  ReorderLevel 
 25 unidad por debajo del mínimo 12 siendo este último valor el valor absoluto referido al campo ReorderLevel

Comment: y cual es el resultado que al momento estás obteniendo

Comment: ProductID: 3 ProductName: Aniseed Syrup UnitsInStock: 13 ReorderLevel 25 unidad por debajo del mínimo 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Considerando que el valor absoluto es el mismo número pero sin signo es decir, la distancia del valor indicado al 0 u origen *(la distancia sin signo negativo)*

Por ejemplo:

```
|-2| = 2
```

Y desde la consola de MySQL usando la función `ABS` quedaría de este modo:

```
SELECT ABS(-350) AS Res;
```

Dando como resultado:

> 350

Si por el contrario lo que tu estás tratando de obtener es un mensaje de Unidad por debajo del mínimo entonces se debería seguir una lógica de comparación tal vez con un `CASE WHEN`

**EJEMPLO**

Declaro 2 variables, una para indicar el stock actual con el que se cuenta y otro para indicar la cantidad mínima que se debe de tener en dicho sotck

```
SET @sockActual = 234;
SET @cantidadMinimaQueDebeExistir = 10;
```

Posterior hago una consulta donde comparo si el `@stockActual` es mayor al `@cantidadMinimaQueDebeExistir` entonces le imprimo al usuario un mensaje diciendo que aún cuenta con stock y en caso contrario le aviso que se le esta acabando dicho stock

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @sockActual >  @cantidadMinimaQueDebeExistir 
THEN 'Aún cuentas con stock' 
ELSE 'Se te esta acabando el stock' END AS Resultado;
```

Y con los valores actuales el mensaje de salida sería:

```
Resultado
Aún cuentas con stock
```

Por lo tanto considero que tu consulta considero debería re orientarse de este modo:

```
Select ProductID, 
       ProductName, 
       UnitsInStock, 
       ReorderLevel, 
       CASE WHEN ReorderLevel < UnitsInStock THEN "unidad por debajo del mínimo"
       ELSE "Cantidad suficiente de stock" END AS Aviso
from products;
```